# Проблема с изучением Yii.

Tags: php, yii

Не могу понять, с какой стороны "подойти" к Yii. Читал официальную документацию, оказалась сложной и далеко не все тонкости объясняют. Смотрел видео курс какого - то чувака, тоже не понравилось. Что делать?

Comment: С изучения php :)

Comment: Я не хочу писать умный комментарий.

@

Я хочу писать разную фигню не в тему.

Comment: учи kohana и проблем не будет

Comment: Пробовал Кохану. С ней слишком много проблем. Просто поставить её и привести в рабочее состояние для меня показалось непосильным трудом, ибо на каждом шаге была какая - нибудь ошибка.

Comment: @mountpoint, еще много разных фреймворков есть. Почему кохана? Потому что только его вы осилили? @mctrane, прав. Очень даже вероятно что проблема таится глубже - в знаниях php

Comment: @VasyOk, я знаю PHP, но освоение фреймворка для меня сложно.

Comment: кохана вообще на какой-то огрызок похожая, лучше тогда самописный фреймфорк использовать.

Comment: если есть хорошие знания php, проблем в изучении фреймворка типа yii быть не должно, мое мнение.

Comment: @VasyOk, да это первый фреймворк который я изучил и успешно применяю. у него низкий порог вхожения и очень удобен при разработке, поэтому я его  порекомендовал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я сам ещё только изучаю Yii и поступил следующим образом.

1) Вначале изучил создание блога, старался понять смысл. Также на этом этапе читал теоретическую часть про MVC, т.к. до этого не был с ней знаком.

2) Затем изучал создание игрового сайта на примере Yii

3) Ещё смотрел и выполнял те же действия как в видео-обзоре какого-то испанца :) Но надолго не хватило.

4) Затем поставил перед собой цели - авторизация, создание страниц, создание задач и т.п. И стал писать свои модули. Попутно накачал ещё исходников таких систем, как Yupe, X2CRM, Zurmo, Phundament и расширений yii-users, yii-auth и т.п.

Сейчас написал уже 2 модуля, скорректировал ещё парочку, и потихоньку читаю всё и развиваюсь дальше. Иногда заглядываю в API. В основном ориентируясь на то, что надо мне.

Comment: Так дело в том, что официальная документация для меня не совсем понятно. Они дают кусок кода, а что он делает - решай сам. Не нравится мне такой подход.

Comment: Создание блога написано достаточно хорошо. Мне было вполне понятно.

Comment: На странице про аутентификацию просто дают кусок кода и просят поставить его в нужное место, даже не описывая то, что он делает.

Comment: по-моему, yii вообще самый простой для понимания фреймворк. Symphony изучать было тяжелее,  не понимаю проблемы

Comment: если не понимаешь кусок про аутентификацию - просто вставь приведённый там код и делай блог дальше. Я так делал. А с аутентификацией разбирался уже потом, когда потребовалось пользователей в БД сохранять, внедрить своё шифрование типа bCrypt и т.п.

Comment: Когда я здесь спрашивал о процедуре изучения Yii, меня "посылали" читать исходники)  
П.С. Самое сложное - паттерн MVC. Дальше пойдет как по маслу)  
П.П.С. Ставь сразу задачу и решай. Например, блог по примеру, но со своими плюшками и изменениями, чтоб разобраться. Еще экстримальнее - взять сразу проект на фрилансе)

Comment: Взять проект на фрилансе, чтобы зафакапить его, и потом его чистить и делать заново другими прогерами.

Answer (score 1):

[Я начал с этого.](http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/57183/)

Comment: и что у вас есть success story ? :) что-то кроме "кто может помочь..." я не видел от вас осознанных действий

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 1):

Тоже сейчас начал учить Yii. Идет как по маслу - воистину отличный фреймворк.

А вот если кусок кода тебе не понятен, возможно, проблема кроется в недостаточном понимании ООП. Убедись, что перед изучением любого MVC фреймворка ты понимаешь, что такое классы, объекты и все жизненнонеобходимое для ориентации в пространстве ООП.

Имхо, человеку который не понимает основ ООП учить фреймворк рановато. Сам в свое время перед изучением Yii получил совет разобраться в ООП. Зато теперь все примеры ясны и легки в понимании. Что касается документации - она прекрасно написана и разжевана.